# Find North-East path with most points

Tags: algorithm

We are given an array of N points on a plane, where each point is represented as (x,y) coordinates. We start at coordinates (0,0) and can move in each step to any point from the given array, which is to the right and above of the current point. The question is to find the length of the longest path, that is a path consisting of the most points.

Example: we are given an array of 3 points [(5,30),(10,10),(20,20)]. We start at (0,0) and suppose we choose to move to (5,30) - then from there we cannot move further since the other points are below the current point. On the other hand, if we first move from (0,0) to point (10,10), then we can continue on to point (20,20), thus achieving a path of length 2, which is the maximum possible here.

Comment: BFS, A* or Dijkstra - just to name a few pathfinding algos - should perfectly do for this purpose.

Comment: But you would need to construct a graph first, since you can  only move in north-east direction. How long would that take ?

Comment: depends. The construction itself can be done implicitly as well. You just need a way to look up all edges. For example you could build a sorted list of lists, where points are ordered by their coordinates with lookup time `O(log n)` and creation in `O(n log n)`. But you'll have to find a way to lookup these relations anyways, so there won't be any way that avoids implicitly building the graph.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ordered by their coordinates" ? The creation of this graph, wether implicit or not would be O(N^2)

Comment: The data-structure I suggest would be a sorted list of sorted lists of coordinates. Outer list is sorted by `y` and the inner lists are sorted by `x` (or vice versa, doesn't matter). This approach would reduce the lookup for all points that are top-left from a point to `O(2 * log n)`. There are quite a few sorting algos that work with `O(n log n)`, so the creation of the data-structure is doable in `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Even with your "list of lists" (outer list sorted by y), you would still need to perform binary search on each of the inner lists that belong to a greater y (there are O(n) inner lists with greater y).  So you actually end up with O(n log n) just to find all the points to the north-east of a given point, which is even worse than O(n) just to scan all the points (to find points to the north-east of a given point) without using "list of lists".

Comment: well, that's a nice calculation. Except for a little mistake: you're calculating with several distinct `n`, so the results are partially incorrect and even if they were correct, they'd be completely useless for means  of comparison. Finding all inner lists runs in `O(log i)`, where `i` is the number of inner lists. The search over all inner lists runs with `O(i * log j)`, where `j` would even in the worst-case be at most `n - i`, with `n` being the number of points. Even in worst-case scenario this would still be better than `O(n)`.

Comment: The precise worst-case would even be O(i * log j_i), where all j_i summed up would result in n. Overall the efficiency would be quite a lot better than O(n). Should be pretty simple to show: `n = j_0 + j_1 + ... + j_(i - 1) >= log j_0 + log j_1 + ... + log j_(i - 1) = efficiency of sorted list approach`. But you can use linear search as well, if you prefer. In the end you just need some way to enumerate all points that lie northeast of a given point.

Comment: Look,  if the N points are [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3),....]  then the graph you're proposing to build would have O(n^2) edges since the first point (1,1) has n-1 points to its northeast, the second point (2,2) has n-2 points, etc so the total number of edges is n*(n-1)/2 which is O(n^2). So any algorithm you could come up with to construct the graph would take at least O(n^2) time.

Comment: Specifically, your method of grouping points by y-value would also not work in the case of distinct values, so even if you could find all the northeast neighbors of each point in less than O(n), it would only work if the points can be partitioned by y value uniformally.

Comment: I guess there was a misunderstanding. I never said anything about the complexity of building the **graph** only about the complexity to build a lookup-table to improve the speed, if we use an implicit definition. As for building the graph itself you're right, but that's another topic. And the idea behind the overall structure isn't to **group** the points, but to provide a simple way to list all points for which `p.y > searched_y` applies, or same for `x`. Even if every point needs to be stored in it's own list, we'd still be capable of optimizing the search based on y-coordinates.

Comment: To run BFS to find the longest path (as you suggested, it's not even clear BFS is the right choice to find the longest path in a DAG), you need to have a graph which has an edge p1->p2 for each pair of points p1,p2 such that p2 is north-east of p1.  We agree that this graph has O(n^2) edges, therefore the running time of BFS (or any other algorithm you suggested) would be at least O(n^2).  Did I not understand you correctly ?

Comment: you did understand that right.

Comment: A running time of O(n^2) would be simple to achieve with a simple dynamic programming algorithm for the original problem. I believe there are better solutions.

Comment: well, a DP-algorithm wouldn't be much more than the reverse of a path-finding algo here, so...